# How to dynamically display documents in brava viewer in EMC xCP 2.1

Tags: documentum, xcp2.x

I have 3 object ID's and 3 documents associated to those object ID's. Now I am using UI Button Click events to load Object ID's into viewer input. But the viewer is displaying only first object id document but not the 2nd and 3rd one when I click the 2nd & 3rd button . I tried to set the object id and content type by the UI event. And even tried the page fragment which helps in loading the data dynamically.

How to configure the viewer so that it can take input dynamically at run time? I am using **xCP 2.1 patch 12**.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share what you have tried yet.

Comment: I tried to set the object id and content type by the UI event. And even tried the page fragment which helps in loading the data dynamically.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load the document in the result list, then configure selection change or cell click event to viewer. hope it will be helpful for you.